# Build fails with SalesForce wsdl in Release mode

Tags: c#, salesforce

I have a C# project in Visual Studio that references the SalesForce WSDL. This have been working fine for years, until recently when I upgraded the project from 4.7.2 to 4.8. Now, when I build the project in Release mode, I get these weird SalesForce errors:

- Cannot convert type 'SalesForceActions.SFDCMetadata.FormItem[]' to
  'SalesForceActions.SFDCMetadata.FormItem'
- Cannot convert type
  'SalesForceActions.SFDCMetadata.NavigationMenuItem[]' to
  'SalesForceActions.SFDCMetadata.NavigationMenuItem'
- Cannot
  implicitly convert type    'SalesForceActions.SFDCMetadata.FormItem'
  to    'SalesForceActions.SFDCMetadata.FormItem[]'
- and other errors similar to that

[image]

The strange thing is, when I build and run in Debug mode, it still works fine without errors.
[image]

I've tried to remove the ".vs" folder several times, but to no avail. I've also tried dong a Clean and Rebuild several times, with no success. And the errors don't have any line number associated with them, so I cannot go to the code in question to look at what is wrong. What could be causing these errors?

Comment: Try doing a clean build.  When you update the Net Library the intermediate object files may not get updated.

Comment: Should have mentioned - tried that too.

Comment: Do you need to update your WSDL files? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_developer_environment_tipsheet.meta/salesforce_developer_environment_tipsheet/salesforce_developer_environment_download_wsdl.htm

Comment: Can you cut the problematic bits out of the wsdl? If you're using only basic data manipulation you don't need these deploy/retrieve metadata bits?

Comment: @jdweng, maybe, but I don't have an active SF account anymore unfortunately.

Comment: Maybe that is why you are failing.  How can you expect to update your code without an account?